# get all numbers with the most frequent digits length in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I'm looking for an answer for a few hours but unfortunately can not find one that suits my problem anywhere.

Suppose I have a certain string that looks like this -

```
str_int = "I'm 35, and I have 2 kids ages 10 and 12"
```

I want to export from these str all the numbers with the most common length. So the satisfy result will be:

```
[35,10,12]
```

Note that the number 2 is not in the array since I only want numbers with the most frequent length.

Also I want to apply this to float numbers as well. so if I have the following string:

```
str_float = "I'm 35.055, and I have 2.100 kids ages 10.0 and 12.505"
```

the expected result will be:

```
[35.055, 12.505]
```

Note that these 2 numbers are 5 digits numbers and the other two numbers are 4 and 3 digits respectively, so I want the most common digits length numbers which is the numbers with the 5 digits.

Hope it makes sense , thanks !

Comment: Sorry , my mistake ...  question updated

Comment: Does `2.100` classify as having 4 digits or 2? (as in `2.1`)

Comment: you can get all the numbers out with `re.findall(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b', str_float )` then you just have to figure out the common length. also go to sleep you owl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the numbers using `re.findall`, find the most frequent length using `collections.Counter`, and then list the numbers that have this length:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

def most_freq(s):
    lst = [(x, len(x) - ('.' in x)) for x in re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)?", s)]
    frequent_length, _ = Counter(x[1] for x in lst).most_common(1)[0]
    return [x[0] for x in lst if x[1] == frequent_length]

str_int = "I'm 35, and I have 2 kids ages 10 and 12"
str_float = "I'm 35.055, and I have 2.100 kids ages 10.0 and 12.505"
str_another = "0.017 0.019 3 1 0.020 2 0.024 3 0.032 0.0157"

print(most_freq(str_int)) # ['35', '10', '12']
print(most_freq(str_float)) # ['35.055', '12.505']
print(most_freq(str_another)) # ['0.017', '0.019', '0.020', '0.024', '0.032']
```

Comment: The max function in this case does not give me exactly what I want. For example I have this lst : 

`[('0.017', 4), ('0.019', 4), ('3', 1), ('1', 1), ('0.020', 4), ('2', 1), ('0.024', 4), ('3', 1), ('0.032', 4),('0.0157', 5)]`

the frequent_length give me 5 , and therfore extract me only the last number with the highest digits - ['0.0157'].
the correct answer would be:
`['0.017','0.019','0.020','0.024','0.032']`

Comment: @יאיראלמליח Oh I don't know what I was thinking hahaha Yes you are right, I made an error there.